# Retrieve the literal string value from reference table based on ID

Tags: c#, linq, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

My project has two different classes. One is for application data which is used for information regarding each service and second one is for reference data which stores the name of the service.

Each customer can have multiple services. I have a view model which contains CustomerServices Type. I am trying to get all customer services of one customer. I get that correctly through linq query but it returns the ID of service but I want to print out the name of the service by looking at the reference data. I can join them in my Linq query but ViewModel does not have attribute for Name of service so how can I show the name of service instead of ID in my razor view?

Linq Query

```
 var data = from profile in _context.Customers
             join services in _context.CustomerServices
             on profile.strUserID equals services.strUserID
             join refServices in _context.ServicesOffered
             on services.lngServiceID equals refServices.lngServiceID
             where profile.strUserID == UserId
             select new { p = profile,  s = services, refs = refServices };
```

My View Model

```
  public class ServiceProvider
    { 
        public CustomerProfile Customer { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<CustomerProfile> CustomerProfiles { get; set; }
        public CustomerServices CustomerServices { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller Code:

```
 var serviceProviderViewModel = new ServiceProvider
            {
                Customer = new CustomerProfile(),
                CustomerServices = new CustomerServices(),
            };

 foreach (var v in data)
            {
                serviceProviderViewModel.Customer = v.p;
                serviceProviderViewModel.CustomerServices = v.s;
                RatingList.Add(v.r); 
            }
            serviceProviderViewModel.CustomerRating = RatingList;
```

Razor View Page

```
 <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.CustomerServices.lngServiceID):$@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.CustomerServices.ServiceRatePerNight)</span>
```

Right now, it prints ID of Service which 10 : $45. How can I get the name of the service and print that instead of id(10)?

Comment: Hi, Check your primary key and foreign key relationship. If the key relationship is correct then you no need to use join in the LINQ. you can achive the service like following. var data = from profile in _context.Customers  where profile.strUserID == UserId select new { p = profile,  s = profile.CustomerServices};

Comment: From the above question. In which table you have service name?

Comment: @Golda ServicesOffered

Comment: Instead of using Model.CustomerServices.lngServiceID you can use Model.refServices.serviceName right?

Comment: <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.refServices.serviceName):$@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.CustomerServices.ServiceRatePerNight)</span>